# How to display the calendar according to event data startdate

Tags: fullcalendar

I have a event data which contains startdate and end date , i want to see the calendar holding that event,now what is happening is it is showing the current week calendar ,but if my event having previous week satrtdate means i have to go to previous week and and i can able to see the event data in calendar..but i want to focus that date calendar at first shot itself..pls do the needful its urgent, i think i have to change something in fullcalendar.js but i dont know where to change pls do needful

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation for FullCalendar... http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/current_date/

This shows parameters that can be set to get the calendar to initate at a particular date.. by default it will always start at todays date.